# Define const variable using eval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants, eval

When I try to define a variable using var, everything is working.

But defining it as const is not working as expected and the variable is undefined.

```js
window.eval("var v = 5;");
document.body.innerHTML += window.v === undefined;

window.eval("const l = 5;");
document.body.innerHTML += window.l === undefined;
```

I have tested it on Chrome and Node.js. Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a way to use let and const in eval, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67322922/387194

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using *let* and *const* in *eval* code doesn't invoke strict mode. *let* and *const* are [*lexicalDeclarations*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-LexicalDeclaration), which limits their scope to the enclosing lexical scope.

A lexical scope is created by a block and by direct call to *eval* (see [*Runtime Semantics: PerformEva step 12*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-performeval)).

Answer (score 11):

That is because `const` turns on the strict mode by default. See what happens when you turn on the strict mode for both examples explicitly:

```js
window.eval("'use strict'; var v = 5;");
document.body.innerHTML += window.v === undefined;

window.eval("'use strict'; const l = 5;");
document.body.innerHTML += window.l === undefined;
```

For more info on the strict mode see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

In particular this part:

> Second, **eval of strict mode code does not introduce new variables into the surrounding scope**. In normal code eval("var x;") introduces a variable x into the surrounding function or the global scope. This means that, in general, in a function containing a call to eval every name not referring to an argument or local variable **must be mapped to a particular definition at runtime** (because that eval might have introduced a new variable that would hide the outer variable). **In strict mode eval creates variables only for the code being evaluated, so eval can't affect whether a name refers to an outer variable or some local variable** [emphasis added]

See also this article:

- [New ES5 strict mode support: new vars created by strict mode eval code are local to that code only](http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/10/new-es5-strict-mode-support-new-vars-created-by-strict-mode-eval-code-are-local-to-that-code-only/)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes :)

Comment: But using *let* and *const* in eval'd code does not invoke strict mode.