# why let keyword does not work with eval()

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(str, a) {
  eval( str );
  console.log( a, b );
}

foo( "var b = 3;", 1 );
```

This works just fine, but when we use let instead of var, it does not work. Why?

Comment: why are you using eval?

Comment: @Tschallacka Why not?  Seems an interesting question about scopes to me.  Even more so when the usual go-to alternative, `new Function`, [behaves differently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w2K6.png).

Comment: Doing this is a bad practice, but I don't know why is this not working with let

Comment: Checked in the browser console,
eval only works with var and not with const and let
even if you do this global scope

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm always curious when someone uses eval to what their tought behind it is.

Comment: Possible useful reading [**eval documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because `eval` introduces a new block of code. The declaration using `var` will declare a variable outside of this block of code, since `var` declares a variable in the function scope.

`let`, on the other hand, declares a variable in a block scope. So, your `b` variable will only be visible in your `eval` block. It's not visible in your function's scope.

[More on the differences between var and let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

**EDIT** : To be more precise `eval` + `let` do, in fact, create a [Lexical Environment](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-lexical-environments). See @RobG response in [Define const variable using eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188732/define-const-variable-using-eval)

Comment: You haven't shown how *eval* crates a block. I think the correct answer is [*linked by Nope*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188732/define-const-variable-using-eval): using *let* in *eval* causes it to run in strict mode, where eval'd code doesn't create variables in the enclosing execution context.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the context in eval is slightly more complex than a few lines of explanation. The official ECMAScript documentation explains how the PerformEval operation actually works according to the external context: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-eval-x (18.2.1 and 18.2.1.1). Not extremely relevant, but it's worth taking a look to that, in my opinion.

Comment: @briosheje—yes, but probably should link to [*ECMAScript 2017*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-eval-x), soon to be replaced by ECMAScript 2018. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: yup, indeed, far more updated (also, it would be interesting to see how it changed in the last years, I don't see some "major" changes, but it's different).

Comment: @briosheje—I don't know if there are changes, like probably 99.999% of scripters I don't ever use *eval* so it's just an oddity. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: I don't as well, but it was an interesting question anyway, otherwise I would have **never** looked at the official eval documentation :D

Comment: @RobG I read Nope's link. And I'm not convinced. Please see my last edit.

Comment: @RogerC—maybe, but there is no evidence of a block either. It is a duplicate question, but perhaps there is not yet a good answer. There is an issue with the acceptance and voting system here on SO that the people who vote on questions often have no idea whether it's a good answer or not. And MDN is no paragon, it can have incorrect information.

Comment: @RogerC eval indeed creates a block scope, and let won't last after the block is done executing. Thanks for the help mate. I appreciate it..

Comment: @RogerC—I've added an answer at the duplicate. It's not block scope nor is it automatic strict mode, it relates to lexical environments which are created by blocks and direct calls to eval.

Comment: @KennyOmega—no it doesn't, there is no  block.

Comment: @RobG - ok, if it does not create a block scope, then what happens? Please add a link to any resource that explains it. Thanks in advance...

Comment: the let keyword is block scoped